# Error: could not find function

Tags: r, function

I have a question related to functions inside loops, I have defined a function like that:

```
FUN <- function(directory=dir, permutations=perm){

# Create directory
dir.create(file.path(getwd(), directory), showWarnings=FALSE)
mypath <- file.path(getwd(), directory)

require('plyr')
scores.v2 <- read.delim('scores.txt', stringsAsFactors=F)

unif.score <- function(b) {
    rand.score <- runif(length(b))
    new.score <- sort(rand.score/sum(rand.score), decreasing=T)
    new.score
}

for (n in 1:permutations){

#  Suffle gene_names in column genes
scores.v2[,2] <- sample(scores.v2[,2])

# Assign new scores according to the uniform distribution
scores.v2 <- ddply(scores.v2, "Locus", transform, Score=unif.score(Score))

# Order data.frame based on Locus and Score
scores.v2 <- scores.v2[order(scores.v2[,1],-scores.v2[,5]),]
return(scores.v2)
   }
}
```

When I execute the function `FUN("permuted", 2)` I get the error `Error: could not find function "unif.score"`. I can fix the problem declaring `unif.score` before running `FUN` but I would like to understand the behaviour of this error message, I think it might be related to environment but I am not sure,

Many thanks

An example of how `scores.txt` looks:

```
 Locus    Gene Link.score Semantic.score      Score
1   ABO     DBH 0.13924316     0.07621951 0.10773133
2   ABO    TSC1 0.00827303     0.18384146 0.09605725
3   ABO   SARDH 0.13924316     0.04573171 0.09248743
4   ABO C9orf96 0.13924316     0.03506098 0.08715207
5   ABO  SLC2A6         NA     0.16859756 0.08429878
6   ABO  RALGDS 0.13924316     0.02195122 0.08059719
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to do with scope and where `ddply` looks for functions and variables. This is why the function `here` was added (in 2012, I think). Using this should work:

```
scores.v2 <- ddply(scores.v2, "Locus", here(transform), Score = unif.score(Score))
```